# How to change Android "Back" arrow to "Down" arrow

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

Very simple question, although after a couple of searches I have come up with nothing. When you bring up the keyboard on Android the "built-in" back button transforms into a "down" button. This is to indicate that you can close the keyboard by pressing this button. I would like to programmatically put the button in this state, to represent that the user can close something that has popped up from the bottom of the screen. How do I do this?

Comment: I am not sure it is possible, as not all the devices have soft buttons for navigation.

Comment: try this ref: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9252354/how-to-customize-the-back-button-on-actionbar

Comment: Only Android ROM developer could complete the your requirement.