# How could i chnage the background color of icon in navigationbar

Tags: android-layout

[image]

How can i draw this type of navigation drawer in which the toolbar icon background is changed?

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on how to ask a proper question and improve yours according the guidelines. First off please share the code you already wrote and describe how it doesnt match your criteria.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can change the home button as your wish. If you are creating app for api level 18 or above 18 then you can change that by using java code.

```
 ActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_custom_nav_home);
```

If you are using support library then you can call something like this,

```
 getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_custom_nav_home);
```

If you want to change the background color then you can create the drawable using xml and change it by using above code.

editing style file is also an easy approach.

Comment: haah haa please refer this question :-). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9252354/how-to-customize-the-back-button-on-actionbar

Comment: Noo Noo i want to chabge only the background color behind the mgs icon