# Is it possible to change up button icon in Navigation Component?

Tags: android, android-navigation, android-jetpack, android-architecture-navigation

I would like to change up button icon in ActionBar that is working with Navigation Component. I've tried several options like:

```
supportActionBar?.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_arrow_left_blue_24dp)
```

in `MainAcitivty` or

```
app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_arrow_left_blue_24dp"
```

in `Toolbar` .xml file and nothing seems to work.

I have a pretty standard setup with

```
setSupportActionBar(appToolbar.toolbar)
setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController)
```

called in `MainActivity:onCreate` method.

I would expect that

```
supportActionBar?.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_arrow_left_blue_24dp)
```

would work, because for example disabling title for `ActionBar` by calling:

```
supportActionBar?.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false)
```

works as expected and title is not set to `Fragment` name while navigating.

What's more, I investigated a little bit and in `ActionBarOnDestinationChangedListener` there is a call to `setNavigationIcon` which is setting an icon to `DrawerArrowDrawable`, which is a little bit weird since I'm not using `Drawer` in my setup.

Also changing to:

```
setupWithNavController(toolbar, navController)
```

is not working because `ToolbarOnDestinationChangedListener` also using the same `DrawerArrowDrawable`.

Answer (score 12):

I have found answer. I checked issue tracker for navigation component and it seems like for now it's impossible to change it without a workaround:

https://issuetracker.google.com/u/1/issues/121078028

Gladly it's still possible, we just need to implement `OnDestinationChangedListener` and change icon there as it's called after `setNavigationIcon` in `AbstractAppBarOnDestinationChangedListener`. Here is a code:

```
navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener { _, _, _ ->
      supportActionBar?.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_arrow_left_blue_24dp)
}
```

You can even differ icon for different destinations.

It's temporary solution as this feature is not there yet. I'm using `1.0.0-alpha09` version of the navigation component.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not use a `supportActionBar` but use **your own toolbar** intead, the solution is as follows.

```
navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener { _, destination, _ ->

        if (destination.id == R.id.myDestination) {

            myToolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.myIcon)
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can implement `NavigationController.OnDestinationChangedListener` and use the `Toolbar.setNavigationIcon` method to set the icon. I would recommend using `AppBarConfiguration.topLevelDestinations` to determine if your destination is a top-level destination and set your icons accordingly. `Kotlin` Example:

```
navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener { _, destination, _ ->
    val isTopLevelDestination = 
        appBarConfiguration.topLevelDestinations.contains(destination.id)
    toolbar.setNavigationIcon(
        if(isTopLevelDestination) R.drawable.ic_menu else R.drawable.ic_back
    )
}
```