# Action Bar disappears after applying background

Tags: android, android-actionbar, background-color

I applied a gradient background to my ActionBar. I can see it in the preview on Eclipse but when I run the app on my phone, the action bar vanishes completely. Why is this happening?

**styles.xml**

```
<resources>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/AppTheme.ActionBarStyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.ActionBarStyle" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/bg_actionbar</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try use to:

```
Drawable d=getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.background_image_name);  
getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(d);
```

and see [this question link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5861870/actionbar-background-image)