# Activity Full Screen in Android

Tags: android

I am trying to make like `Trello` application, see in the screenshot of Trello, they covered complete screen with background but still time, network show in title bar, I want to do same in my application such that set background  to complete full screen and should show network and time.

[image]

I am trying this but it didn't work for me.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

[image]

### Update

[image]

Comment: Not sure what your target sdk version is, but you can do this natively starting from API level 19 (4.4) https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive.html

Comment: Maybe they just [set the background image](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5861870/11683)?

Answer (score 1):

> **Removing the action bar**
>
> You can hide the action bar at runtime by calling hide(). For example:

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.hide();
```

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html

For a translucent system bar (like in trello) see this:

> **Translucent system bars**
>
> You can now make the system bars partially translucent with new
>   themes, Theme.Holo.NoActionBar.TranslucentDecor and
>   Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar.TranslucentDecor. By enabling translucent
>   system bars, your layout will fill the area behind the system bars, so
>   you must also enable fitsSystemWindows for the portion of your layout
>   that should not be covered by the system bars.
>
> If you're creating a custom theme, set one of these themes as the
>   parent theme or include the windowTranslucentNavigation and
>   windowTranslucentStatus style properties in your theme.

http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.4.html#UI

Comment: No, now it hide the network, battery status in the title, see I want something like trello

Comment: see I added screenshot in the question

Comment: this does not hide the battery status, your other code hides it (see your screenshot before the update) this means comment the `getWindow().setFlags(...)` line

Comment: @Mick remember to accept answers, if they helped you, so they don't stay open

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,windowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Android introduced a Immersive Full Screen Mode concept from Android 4.4, here you can see https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive.html that solved my problem.