# Android ActionBar Background Image

Tags: android, android-actionbar, background-image, image-size

Can I set a background image to the actionbar but without it fitting the size off the image? I want to set the background and to fit the image in the actionbar size. How can I do that?

Comment: did you tried anything?if yes post your code

Comment: Deplicated http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5861870/actionbar-background-image

Comment: check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8024706/how-do-i-change-the-background-color-of-the-actionbar-of-an-actionbaractivity-us

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar(); 

 BitmapDrawable background = new BitmapDrawable (BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),   
 R.raw.actionbar_background)); 

 background.setTileModeX(android.graphics.Shader.TileMode.REPEAT); 

 actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(background);
```

[See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5861870/actionbar-background-image)

Comment: new BitmapDrawable (BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
R.raw.actionbar_background)); is deprecated